# start a SBATCH array with big number?

Tags: arrays, jobs, biginteger, slurm, sbatch

Is it possible to start a SBATCH job array, i.e. `#SBATCH ––array=1-5`, with a big number, e.g. `#SBATCH ––array=12-25` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can start at a value larger than 1, but the values must remain below the `MaxArraySize` value configure in `slurm.conf`.

Otherwise, you will get an error:

```
$ scontrol show config | grep -i array
MaxArraySize            = 1001
$ sbatch --array 1000-1005 --wrap hostname
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid job array specification
```

Should that be the case, you can use a Bash array to hold the values and then use `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` as index into that array:

```
...
#SBATCH --array=0-5
...
VALUES=({1000..1005})
THISJOBVALUE=${VALUES[$SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID]}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have you tried already? See `man sbatch` under `-a, --array`.